# Android Maps v2 crashes on load

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an app which is based on Google Maps Api V2. The app shows the map on startup and up until now, Google Maps was the only map provider available. The only exception that I have is this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.c.n.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.c.n.(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.c.e.(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.l.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.cv.f(Unknown Source)
```

I am not sure if this is related to [this reported issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9021) or not but this is not the first issue appearing from Google Maps (included in Google Play Services) for which I don't have any choice but to wait for a fix. Because of this I decided to also add Open Street Maps as an alternate provider.

Adding a new map provider was easy. Making the workaround for the crash was not so easy. I have spent about 3 weeks trying to find a solution to this problem. I feel that I've tried everything so I came here to see if there are any other solutions for this.

Until now, I tried to catch the exception with an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` which seems that it worked once (about 2 weeks ago) and I couldn't managed to reproduce the same code again.

Forcing the Google Maps to crash (by changing the api key label in Manifest) on my device was actually caught by the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` but unfortunately it didn't worked for the real problem on my users device.

I tried to use both `getMap()` and `getMapAsync()` with the same result.

I tried to add `try-catch` blocks everywhere I had a connection with Google Maps like where I start the fragment and over `getMapAsync()` with no success.

I tried to start Google Maps in another main activity (following the same example from [Google Maps Api V2 guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start?hl=en)) without any connection with my other app activities but I had no success in catching the exception that made the app crash.

I forced the app to start with Open Street Maps and it worked just fine.

My plan was to catch the Google Maps crash and restart the app with Open Street Maps instead but I really couldn't find a good solution for this. I mean, I managed to make this work but it only works on my device (Xperia Z1 Compact with Android 5.1.1) where I can't reproduce the issues that my users have.

Until now, I have 2 users complaining of this issue over email. They both have Android 4.2.1 with Kernel version 3.4.5 and Google Play Services version 8.4.89 (2428711-036).

I also have this exception in Google Developer Console, reported by other users without a specific device pattern (I don't know if this is related to the NPE that I am trying to bypass right now):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {android.package.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3050)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2447)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.google.a.a.ae.a(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.k.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.k.a(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.y.a(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.bd.a(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.ev.a(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.z.a(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.y.a(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
  at com.google.android.gms.maps.a.l.a(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.maps.o.a(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.b.f.a(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.b.b.a(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.b.b.a(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.maps.n.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(SourceFile:1789)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:955)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1138)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1120)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(SourceFile:1939)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(SourceFile:447)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(SourceFile:436)
  at android.support.v7.app.ad.onPostResume(SourceFile:138)
  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6089)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3039)
... 11 more
```

What do you think that I could do to catch the Google Maps crash or what workaround should I do to be able to load Open Street Maps if Google Maps crashes on startup?

Comment: call that in oncreate instead of onresume.

Comment: write code in which line you are getting crash

Comment: @ARMV: I am not calling anything in onResume. I am setting the map fragment in onCreate. I don't have a line where I get the crash because I don't get the crash.

Comment: @DanielNugent: Unfortunately I can't reproduce this issue and the logs show obfuscated code because Google Maps code is obfuscated so I can't add any other debug stack trace.